# add lines into tex file

Tags: emacs, output, write-file

I have this tex file coming from matlab.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=5,
ymin=2,
ymax=10
]
\addplot [color=red,line width=4.0pt,only marks,mark=*,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
1   2   \\
2   4   \\
3   6   \\
4   8   \\
5   10  \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

I want to add `xlabel` and `ylabel` inside it like

```
xmin=1,
xmax=5,
ymin=2,
ymax=10,
xlabel=X,
ylabel=Y,
```

if I run another latex file like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115379/write-and-read-from-a-latex-temporary-file).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newwrite\tempfile
\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\tempfile=lists.tex
\immediate\write\tempfile{xlabel=X,}
\immediate\write\tempfile{ylabel=Y,}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\input{lists}
\end{document}
```

Can I write these to specific lines?

Comment: There may be a TeX-specific solution but I would use `sed`, the stream editor, for it.

Comment: Open the file, edit stuff, close the file. I really don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Why don't you add the axis labels in Matlab in the first place?

Comment: If it is generic options you want to add to the `axis` environment, use the `extraAxisOptions` argument to `matlab2tikz`, e.g. `matlab2tikz('file.tex','extraAxisOptions','xlabel=this,ylabel=that')`.

Answer (score 2):

The keys `xlabel` and `ylabel` can also be set *outside* of the `tikzpicture` from matlab via `\pgfplotsset`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newdimen\figurewidth
\newdimen\figureheight

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \pgfplotsset{xlabel=$X$, ylabel=$Y$}
  \setlength{\figurewidth}{5cm}
  \setlength{\figureheight}{5cm}
  % Matlab export
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
  width=\figurewidth,
  height=\figureheight,
  scale only axis,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=5,
  ymin=2,
  ymax=10
  ]
  \addplot [color=red,line width=4.0pt,only marks,mark=*,mark
  options={solid},forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{
  1   2   \\
  2   4   \\
  3   6   \\
  4   8   \\
  5   10  \\
  };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using only emacs replace-regexp function:

`M-x replace-regexp RET \(ymax=[0-9]+\) RET \1, C-q C-j xlabel=X, C-q C-j ylabel=Y`